# Is there a way to debug and/or validate Microsoft Word document XML generated by python-docx?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I am building a simple framework for generating Microsoft Word document reports using the python-docx library. Occasionally, when I generate a document I run into a problem in which the docx file is generated successfully by python-docx, but then the docx file will not open in Microsoft Word and an error message like this is displayed: [Microsoft Word 'Unspecified Error' Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekWHa.png)

By working through my code step by step - progressively inserting more and more content into the python-docx Document and then attempting to open the generated docx file after each content addition - I was able to identify the code which was causing the error. As it turned out, the error was caused when I attempted to insert an empty pandas dataframe using the code below:

```
def insert_as_table(df: pd.DataFrame, document: Document) -> Document:

    # compute parameters
    n_rows = len(df) + 1
    n_cols = len(df.columns)

    # create table object
    table = document.add_table(rows=n_rows, cols=n_cols)

    # fill header cells with text
    for header_cell, col in zip(table.rows[0].cells, df.columns):
        header_cell.text = str(col)

    # fill cells with strings
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        for table_cell, (j, data) in zip(table.rows[i + 1].cells, row.iteritems()):
            table_cell.text = str(data)

    return document
```

My solution was to add input validation - checking that the dataframe was not empty before attempting to insert it:

```
def insert_as_table(df: pd.DataFrame, document: Document) -> Document:

    if df.empty:
        raise ValueError('df is empty. Cannot insert an empty dataframe as a table.')

    etc...
```

While this worked, the bug hunt process leads to my question: is there a way to debug and/or validate the Microsoft Word XML code that is generated by python-docx? In regards to validation, is there a way that I can validate that the docx file generated by python-docx is valid and will be able to be opened by Microsoft Word (without actually having to open it using Word)? In regards to debugging, is there a way that I can view and debug the docx XML code to identify where an issue is located (and perhaps obtain some clues as to where the issue is being generated in the Python code)? Such a tool or method would likely have saved me a significant amount of time in the bug hunt that I described above and perhaps will save me time in the future as well. Thanks much for your time and thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, a `.docx` file is a Zip archive conforming to the Open Packaging Convention (OPC). In OPC parlance, such an archive represents a *package* and the (main) files within it each represent a *part*.

Files such as images are *binary* parts, but most parts are XML documents. The valid contents of those XML parts is specified by one or more XML Schema (.xsd) file that accompanies the spec. Those are available in the `/ref/xsd/` folder of the python-docx GitHub repository https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/tree/master/ref/xsd.

These can be used to validate parts individually. Since a typical Word file is mostly the `document.xml` part, the most mileage would probably come from validating that one.

The same `lxml` library that `python-docx` uses can be used for validation. You should refer to the [lxml documentation](https://lxml.de/validation.html) for that procedure.

This will definitely catch a schema-invalid package part, but I expect it could not catch all possible XML documents that would cause a so-called "repair error" on load into Word.

Still, it might be worth trying. I'd love to hear whether it caught the error you had above, which I expect was a zero-rows and zero-columns table.

Comment: This is very informative and has definitely helped point me in the right direction. In all honesty, I had no idea that a .docx file was actually a Zip archive! I've made some progress towards my goal, but I haven't gotten all the way there as when I attempt to the validate `document._element.xml` against the .xsd files, I receive an `etree.XMLSyntaxError` that states `Element '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}document': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. (<string>, line 0)`. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can validate on the string produced by `document._element.xml`; you'll want to go direct to the bytes of the part, like `document.part.blob` if you want to use `python-docx` to navigate the package. There might still be a problem with that, but that's what I'd try next. Also you'll need to have the `wml.xsd` schema file loaded somewhere, that's where the `<w:document>` element definition is found I expect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the wml.xsd schema. After I adjusted that file slightly by adding a local `schemaLocation="xml.xsd"`  for the `namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"` import, I was able to validate document xml against it once I removed a problematic element `mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14"` from the document xml. In the end, it turned out that a document containing a zero-rows, zero-columns table would validate successfully against the wml.xsd schema. No exceptions were raised. So I guess I'll keep on validating those dataframes before attempting to insert them. Thanks again!